# Since $C_{00}$ is both dense in $C_0$ and in $l^p$, is it true that $C_0=l^p$?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, normed-spaces

Let $$c_{00}=\{x=(x_k)_{k=1}^\infty \in l^\infty: \exists N \text { such that } x_k=0 \forall k>N \}$$, and $$c_{0}=\{x=(x_k)_{k=1}^\infty \in l^\infty: \lim_{k \to +\infty} x_k=0 \}$$

In my lectures we have proven that $c_{00}$ is both dense in $c_0$ and in $l^p$. I think the closure of a set is unique, right?, and that A is dense in X if the closure of A is X. Then that should imply that $c_0=l^p$, which I don't think is true. What is going on here?

Comment: $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in both $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R} - \sqrt{2}$, but $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R} - \sqrt{2}$ are different.

Comment: @David Lui but the closure of $\mathbb{Q}$ is $\mathbb{R}$ not the other one, isn't it? Isn't that what being dense means? A is dense in X if cl(A)=X

Comment: For $X \in \{c_0,\ell^p\}$, $c_{00}$ *is dense in* $X$ means that the **closure of $c_{00}$ in $X$** is $X$. Now, the closure of $c_{00}$ in $c_0$ and the closure of $c_{00}$ in $\ell^p$ they don't have to be the same.

Comment: The subtlety is that a closure is taken with respect to some space. The closure of $c_{00}$ IN $c_0$ is $c_0$ and the closure of $c_{00}$ IN $\ell^p$ is $\ell^p$.